# Is it possible to use mass transit with ServiceBusAttribute isolated functions with Rabbit MQ locally without recompile

Tags: docker-compose, azure-functions, rabbitmq, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have started exploring the use of MassTransit as an abstraction over the Azure Service Bus as a way of being able to run my full system locally via docker / compose. My vision is to have an Azure Container Register with all of the component parts in images that can be pulled to the local machine via docker compose whilst running one of those parts in debug mode (e.g. a function or an api).

As we know from countless questions around this, it's not currently possible to run the Azure Service Bus locally via any emulation so finding MassTransit as an abstraction was useful. I have since used RabbitMQ locally and think it might be a good fit for local development.

My host builder startup for my test function is this:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true).Build();

var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureServices(s =>
{
    s.AddMassTransit(x => x.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((cntx, cfg) =>
        {
            var settings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(RabbitMqSettings)).Get<RabbitMqSettings>();
            
            cfg.Host(settings.Uri, c =>
            {
                c.Username(settings.UserName);
                c.Password(settings.Password);
            });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("organisations", e => e.Consumer<OrganisationCreatedConsumer>());
        });
    }));
})
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults();

busController.StartAsync();
```

I'm using isolated functions in Azure now and have successfully run up MassTransit with the consumer/producer model defined in the ConfigureServices but I'm wondering if there is a way of using [ServiceBusTrigger] attributes in a GENERIC way that can somehow switch between the two abtractions (Rabbit vs Azure Service Bus). I've seen some examples that use compile time directives to swap in the different attributes [RabbitMqTrigger] vs [ServiceBusTrigger] but that would require different docker images to be built and pulled locally so that doesn't fit with the build once approach.

```
[Function("Function1")] // This attribute will fail locally as it's specific to Azure 
--> public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("organisations", "mysub", Connection = "*myconnectionstring*")] string mySbMsg)
{
   _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

Failing the above, is there a way of using the MassTransit Consumer model and somehow reporting the events in the Function Monitor as being an actual FunctionName and outcome? It's very nice to be able to go to the app insights view and see the executions, but without the service bus bindings being exposed, I see no way of handling this in a nice fashion.

Am I asking for a moon on a stick?

Comment: You're on the right path of testing consumers using RabbitMQ locally vs. Service Bus in Azure. However, what you're trying to do with the whole function substrate is just odd to me, and not something I'd even have a guess of how to support. But using MassTransit with RabbitMQ locally while using ASB in Azure is quite normal. You shouldn't be creating a separate bus in any case though.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson! Thankful for your attention to this. The 'reason' if there is such a thing is that I'm using function bindings for all of my current service bus triggers and I just wanted to be able to substitute what I had in the handler method as I already had my own handler factory present. But it sounds like I should wholesale remove my version and use masstransits consumer mechanism and lose the visibility of the function invocations in the portal? Ah yes, duplicate bus on the CreateUsingRabbitMq. Thanks I'll remove that one and put it in the configuration above.

Comment: @TheSenator, have u got any solution for this?

Comment: @sourav I don't believe it's posible to have both attributes AND the generic message consumer/publisher approach as the attributes only work with the azure service bus and would cause errors on load when running locally. So I've done away with the attributes for my version for now.